# Cómo recuperar el PATH de Windows?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, variables, rutas

Mientras configuraba unas variables de entorno eliminé accidentalmente mi PATH. Ahora muchoas de mis programas no funcionan y eran tantas direcciones que no recuerdo todas y mi eclipse aún no quiere levantar. Hay alguna manera en la que pueda recuperar esa data?

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿No tienes backup de tu sistema?

Comment: Donde puede encontrar el backup?

Comment: Con buscar _"Restaurar sistema"_ en el menú inicio de Windows basta, mira a ver si tienes algún backup reciente y puedes restaurar. Eso sí, se pueden borrar algunos datos, asi que realiza una copia de documentos sensibles antes.

Comment: Configurando el path de windows para el servidor Xampp, se me elimino la ruta del eclipse y no arrancaba. Quite de panel de control, en programa el java y el jdk, me los baje de nuevo por la pagina de ninite.com y me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Dificil que puedas recuperar todos los Path , pero para que eclipse funcione necesitas apuntar la variable de entorno PATH a tu JDK sera algo similar a esto :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin
```

Comment: Esas son las variables que ya puse. Coloque el bin del jdk, del jre, x86 y el de x64.y aun no funciona